How to remove Incoming/Outgoing changes graph in VSCode?
In July 2024, VSCode (update 1.92) introduced this new Incoming/Outgoing changes graph:

I don't really need it since I use another tool for that, and it is polluting my workspace.
Is there a way to remove it? I tried clicking around but could not find it. The update notes also don't specify a way to disable this feature.

This feature is slowing my computer on git that has thousand commit more, and i can't do anything in git operations while wait this feature appear.

here I created 20 second video to change this setting  https://youtu.be/JfD3OLGMCjc

It's a fine commit graph, but why on earth would I want it showing in the panel I use to navigate to my files altered since the last commit?

Agreed @GregoryCosmoHaun - I would assume this will be turned off with a later version. Pretty bad UX

The thing is, if there was a way to collapse it half of us wouldn't be here because it wouldn't be nearly as annoying as it is now. Why didn't VSCode engineers think well about this before adding the feature?

Since the August 2024 update (v1.93), the json setting for the graph has been rendered useless:
  "scm.showHistoryGraph": false,

You can now instead just right click on the tab and disable it manually using the GUI. Just make the the 'Source Control Graph' have no 'tick' symbol next to it

True, now it's just another tab on the right side menu (like Commits, Branches, Remotes..) , and we can right click and disselect it

Just add:
"scm.showHistoryGraph": false

to your JSON settings.
Reference: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/224616

…and if you don't want to see incoming/outgoing changes at all, see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/192290: "scm.showIncomingChanges": "never", "scm.showOutgoingChanges": "never".

…or not? https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/224517

Judging by the huge volume of responses to this, the feature should really be off by default. If you work with any decent sized repository the tree is going to be massive.

"scm.showIncomingChanges": "never" and "scm.showOutgoingChanges": "never" could also be set in order to remove ALL info from scm panel

I couldn't edit the JSON file. Is that new? Anyways, over the UI settings, that worked. Thanks!

Uncheck the "Show History Graph" option


here is a guide step by step:

Open settings editor, you can do this in several ways,

Windows

Navigate to File > Preferences > Settings
Use the Command Palette by pressing Ctrl+ Shift + P, then type Preferences: Open Settings
Use the keyboard shortcut Ctrl + , (comma)


Mac

Navigate to Code > Settings > Settings
Use the Command Palette by pressing Cmd + Shift + P on macOS, then type Preferences: Open Settings
Use the keyboard shortcut Cmd + , (comma)




Type showhistorygraph in search bar
Uncheck the SCM: Show History Graph option

Or you can also edit settings directly in the settings.json file

Use the Command Palette by pressing Ctrl+Shift+P or Cmd+ Shift + P
then type Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)
add "scm.showHistoryGraph": false

Open the settings.json file in the .vscode folder in your workspace for workspace settings

@Nzall That's a weird statement considering there's nothing in this that's particularly unique to AI/ML tools. Maybe what you mean by "slightly modified AI" is actually just human whose first language isn't English.

@Nzall, probably because it's too thorough. Answers written by a human will rarely explain three different ways to get to the settings times two operating systems, plus an extra option of editing the file directly. This also smells of AI to me, but there are enough inconsistencies for me to believe that it actually is.

Update:  Version 1.93 has moved the graph to the "Source Control Graph" view as mentioned below.

The Visual Studio Code maintainers have removed (or will remove in an upcoming update) the graph from the source control view and they are moving it to its own view called "Source Control Graph."
It seems users found it too distracting when the working tree was clean, among other reasons.  Expect this graph to be somewhere else within the IDE in the future.

In user settings.json add
  "scm.showHistoryGraph": false,

If you want to get rid of Incoming/outgoing completely

change show incoming/outgoing changes to never



This option isn't available for me. (There was just an update so maybe it was removed?)
If you also can't find this option, you can move this section out to its own tab by dragging the gray bar onto the activity bar on the left. This way it won't bother you when working with other source control features but it's still available if you want it. And if you really don't, you can right click on the new icon that gets created and hide it.

In case you don't update your VSCode settings often, on a Mac, Go to Code > Preferences > Settins

Then once the Settings tab opens, search for "showHistoryGraph" or "Show History Graph" and uncheck the first one, "SCM: Show History Graph"


This is just repeating this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78835413/2745495

Code is showing the entire commit history for branches that don't have an upstream, which is pretty wild considering they didn't implement any display limit or collapse functionality.
The feature actually looks useful and meaningful when you have set an upstream.
If you'd like to keep the graph for some branches and just disable it for certain branches or repositories, you can set an upstream branch. If you don't have an upstream you want to use, you can do the hacky trick of setting a branch's upstream to itself. For example, if your branch is main...
git remote add here .
git fetch here
git branch --set-upstream-to here/main

Big disclaimer: normally git prevents you from setting a branch as its own upstream. Adding a repo as its own remote is the workaround. I have no idea whether this will cause damage to your repository.

In theory there’s no problem. Pushing will fail because the destination is not bare, though that can be overridden. That might lead to weirdness. But you could also unset the upstream, presumably.

How does this relate to the question asked? :|

@mathan26, the question is about how to remove or disable the graph. This answer describes how to disable or remove the graph on a per repository/branch basis, so I think it adds something. Why don't you like the answer?
